# Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing ) after argument list, but no extra }'s?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

so I am doing this assignment for a class and I stumbled upon this when validating it through google inspect.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing ) after argument list.`

So I checked on this site and saw that people had extra }'s. So I checked my document for that but didn't find any extras. Are there any other reasons this SyntaxError could be happening?

Here is the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Age Requirement</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function age() {
var age = prompt("What is your age?" "");
if (age < 21 || age = "") {
alert("You have not entered an age, or you are too young to buy tobacco.");
} 
else {
alert("Congratulations, you can buy tobacco.");
}
}
    
age()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot have two string literals without operators between them `"" ""` ...

Comment: It actually means "*missing `,` or `)` after first argument*".

Comment: Oh, thank you @JonasWilms, I'm relatively new to javascript, so sorry if the question seems rather weird.

Comment: Btw, the next thing you'll get caught on is that `=` is assignment but `==` is comparison.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi I was able to fix that.

Comment: @amateur_coder no worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a comma in your prompt. Change it to

```
var age = prompt("What is your age?", "");
```

Where you have in this case a blank default value.